# RichFaces Page Theme -- Include CSS file?

Tags: html, css, jsf, themes, richfaces

I'm toying with creating a custom RichFaces page theme per the [instructions here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingaThemeforrichpageComponent).  I've run the Maven commands and it creates my initial page template, along with a .xcss file where I'm supposed to place my stylesheet properties.  I would like, however, to include several different CSS files in my page theme, rather than define them in one huge file.  It would make it much easier if I could include, for example, the 960.css file in its own file so that the CSS code is easier to read and edit.

I notice that [the instructions](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingaThemeforrichpageComponent) talk about how to reference an image file in the XCSS file by using this tag:

```
<f:resource f:key="/org/richfaces/docs/renderkit/html/images/img01.gif" />
```

Is there a similar mechanism for including more than one .xcss file in my page theme?  I tried simply using:

```
<f:resource f:key="/org/richfaces/docs/renderkit/html/css/960.css" />
```

However, I get an XML parsing error, so I'm clearly doing something wrong.  Is there a better way to include multiple CSS files in my page theme project and then reference them in the page theme itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who is struggling with this problem, it appears as though the `<h:styles />` tag (xmlns:h="http://jsf.exadel.com/header") is designed to solve this very problem.  Place your .xcss files under your renderkit/html directory in your theme, and then reference them using relative paths.  i.e.

`<h:styles>css/myothercss.xcss</h:styles>`